# AppClassLoader error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type ... when weaving type

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.EhCacheCacheConfiguration
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.EhCacheCacheConfiguration
when weaving classes 
when weaving
```

What this warnings are actually about?
I have created one *@Aspect* class in my app, and it is working correctly.
My knowledge atm is not deep. Only I know that moment exists when the app weave my aspect to the classes where it should be used.
Warnings are confusing me. Why the app wants to weave classes I see in this logs?

*PS* stack**overflow** gave me an answer how to avoid warnings (aop.xml). But I would like to know what the reason of this warning initially. Will it be the problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your pointcut is too broad, trying to weave into all existing Spring components, including Spring's own ones, fox example class `EhCacheCacheConfiguration`, which is a Spring Boot class. Obviously, that class references Spring Core class `EhCacheCacheManager` which is unavailable at the time of trying to weave the aspect into the configuration class or into one of the components/beans declared there.

This is a classical boot-strapping problem with global "weave the whole world" aspects. I do not think that an `aop.xml` file will help you here, because probably, like most users, you are using the default AOP framework Spring AOP, not native AspectJ, but `aop.xml` is only for AspectJ load-time weaving configuration. What you want to do instead is to limit the target scope of your aspect by adding something like `&& within(my.target.package..*)` to the pointcut. Probably the error goes away then.